# Haskell add 2 maps

Tags: haskell

How can I retain the value of list 2 in the next example to compute the sum of 2 maps in haskell?

```
listsSumm :: Eq a => Bag a -> Bag a -> Bag a
listsSumm [] [] = []
listsSumm bag1 bag2 
       | q1==q2 = (q1,v1+v2):(listsSumm rBag1 rBag2)  
       | otherwise = bagSum [(q1,v1)] rBag2
       where ((q1,v1):rBag1) = bag1
             ((q2,v2):rBag2) = bag2
```

and my imput is:

```
listSumm [("a",1),("c",1),("d",1),("b",1)] [("a",2),("c",1),("b",1),("d",1)]->[("a",3),("c",2),("d",2)]
```

How can I retain the content of the second list to keep reevaluating it after a test has finished?

Comment: why is `("b",2)` missing in the output?

Comment: That's the thing. It tests for d until the end of the bag, and for b, it doesn't know to come back to test all the list for it. How can I do this?

Comment: How can I make it test all the list 2 for each head in a?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you seem to be working with `Map`s, what you're trying to do can be done quite straightforwardly:

```
import qualified Data.Map as M

sumOfMaps :: M.Map String Int -> M.Map String Int -> M.Map String Int
sumOfMaps = M.unionWith (+)
```

If you don't want to rely on `Data.Map` you can use the following solution to merge your lists:

```
import Data.Function ( on )
import Data.List ( groupBy, sortBy )
import Data.Ord ( compare )

sumOfLists :: [(String, Int)] -> [(String, Int)] -> [(String, Int)]
sumOfLists l1 l2 = map merge . collect $ l1 ++ l2
  where collect = groupBy ((==) `on` fst) . sortBy (compare `on` fst)
        merge xs@(x:_) = (fst x, sum $ map snd xs)
```